# Equal height of children of unrelated parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to have an equal height of two unrelated divs. Basically, I need to equalize the height of Parent B's child to Parent A's child. Below is the image to highlight what it is about:

[image]

Any idea how this can be accomplished with jQuery. Most of the equal height solutions I came across are about children of the same parent.

The code I used is for children within a container.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.containers').each(function(){  
      var min_highestBox = 0;
      $('.columns', this).each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > min_highestBox) {
          min_highestBox = $(this).height(); 
        }
      });               
      $('.columns',this).height(min_highestBox);
    }); 
});
```

```css
.containers {border:1px solid; width:100%; display:inline-block;}
.columns {border:1px solid red; padding: 20px; min-width:20%; float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">
    <div class="columns">This is<br />the highest<br />column</div>
    <div class="columns">One line</div>
    <div class="columns">Four<br />lines<br />the highest<br />column</div>
</div>
<div class="containers">
    <div class="columns">One line</div>
    <div class="columns">Two<br>lines</div>
    <div class="columns">One line</div>
</div>
```

I have tried it with a CSS grid but in this specific situation, a CSS grid is not a solution.

Update: the actual containers are both separate and independent of each other:

```css
.a, .b {border:2px solid; padding: 25px; float:left; width: 200px;}
.a div, .b div {border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="a">Parent A
<div>Child of A <br> some additional text</div>
</div>

<div class="b">Parent B
<div>Child of B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you tried? can you please share your latest code?

Comment: @RohitVerma - just added the code I used previously in my question above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal height sections within flexbox columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592757/equal-height-sections-within-flexbox-columns)

Comment: While this can be achieved without it, I do feel that this is the sort of problem that CSS subgrid was meant for (and will be very happy when browsers other than Firefox supports it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that they can't be placed inside a wrapper you can make use of a sorting from lowest to heighest and apply the heighest value to all affected nodes and a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to easily monitor changes on these nodes to call the height-adjust routine again.

#### For equal height of parents:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const selector = ".containers";
  function resize() {
    const nodes = $(selector)
          .css("height", "auto")
          .sort((a, b) => $(a).height() - $(b).height()),
      heighest = nodes.last().height();
    if (nodes.first().height() != heighest)
      $(selector).css(`height`, `${heighest}px`);
  }

  resize();

  const observer = new MutationObserver(resize);
  $(selector).each((idx, el) => observer.observe(el, { childList: true, subtree: true }));


  // Examples:
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".columns").first().append("<br>Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor<br>sit<br>Amet");
  }, 1500);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".columns").last().append("<br>Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor<br>sit<br>Amet");
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".columns").last().append("<br>Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor<br>sit<br>Amet");
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.containers {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.columns {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">
  <div class="columns">This is<br>the highest<br>column</div>
  <div class="columns">One line</div>
  <div class="columns">Four<br>lines<br>the highest<br>column</div>
</div>
<div class="containers">
  <div class="columns">One line</div>
  <div class="columns">Two<br>lines</div>
  <div class="columns">One line</div>
</div>
```

#### For equal height of childs:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const selector = ".columns";
  function resize() {
    const nodes = $(selector)
          .css("height", "auto")
          .sort((a, b) => $(a).height() - $(b).height()),
      heighest = nodes.last().height();
    if (nodes.first().height() != heighest)
      $(selector).css(`height`, `${heighest}px`);
  }

  resize();

  const observer = new MutationObserver(resize);
  $(selector).each((idx, el) => observer.observe(el, { childList: true, subtree: true }));


  // Examples:
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".columns").first().append("<br>Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor<br>sit<br>Amet");
  }, 1500);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".columns").last().append("<br>Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor<br>sit<br>Amet");
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(".columns").last().append("<br>Lorem<br>Ipsum<br>Dolor<br>sit<br>Amet");
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.containers {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.columns {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">
  <div class="columns">This is<br>the highest<br>column</div>
  <div class="columns">One line</div>
  <div class="columns">Four<br>lines<br>the highest<br>column</div>
</div>
<div class="containers">
  <div class="columns">One line</div>
  <div class="columns">Two<br>lines</div>
  <div class="columns">One line</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider an extra wrapper you can do it with only CSS

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* eqaul containers */
}
.containers {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex; /* equal childs */
}

.columns {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="containers">
    <div class="columns">This is<br />the highest<br />column</div>
    <div class="columns">One line</div>
    <div class="columns">Four<br />lines<br />the highest<br />column</div>
  </div>
  <div class="containers">
    <div class="columns">One line</div>
    <div class="columns">Two<br>lines</div>
    <div class="columns">One line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have played with it but the CSS grid doesn't offer a solution in this specific situation. JS could offer a solution to enforce one's height on another... possibly.

Comment: @AsifRaza I have provided a code that demonstrate a *working solution* for this *specific situation*

Comment: No doubt that this is one of the best solutions. But, in my case, both containers are not part of the same wrapper. The example I gave was about what I have tried and was looking for a solution with jQuery ...

Comment: @AsifRaza *But, in my case, both containers are not part of the same wrapper* --> then you should give you real *case* if you want to get accurate answers. We can only answer based on the content of the question

Comment: the image I shared is exactly what the problem is. I have just added the code for it as well. Both are independent containers.