# How to make cards height equal and place the shop button at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

in the above image 1st card height is streched beacuse of long title. and because of which 2nd card's height is also streched but the shop button is not placed at the bottom

I want to place the button at the bottom no matter what is the height of card

Comment: Share your codes if possible. It's hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal height of children of unrelated parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71735364/equal-height-of-children-of-unrelated-parents)

Answer (score 1):

You can give relative position to the parent button and absolute position to the button and style like this

```
 .buttoncontainer{
     Position: relative ;
 }

.buttonclass{ 
      Position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
  }
```

Maybe this method is useful for you